# How to undo a survival object (return a data frame)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, rms

After generating a model using `cph()` from `rms`, calling `model$y` will return a survival object.  Is there a function that will "undo" the survival object and return a data frame?

I would like to be able to use a survival object as a argument for a function I am writing, but I also need the response data.  I am trying to avoid using the data as an argument and creating the model inside the function.

A minimal working example is provided below:

```
library(rms)
# generate data
time <- c(82, 73, 89, 79, 72, 87, 103, 83, 100, 79)
event <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
covar <- c(15, 11, 11, 20, 12, 13, 10, 11, 10, 14)
df <- data.frame(time, event, covar)

# Cox model
dd <- datadist(df)
options(datadist = 'dd')
model <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ covar, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv=TRUE, data=df)

# returns a survival object
model$y

# what I want is a data frame
want <- data.frame(time, event)
want
```

Comment: Try using `broom::tidy(model$y)`  (untested)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite what I'm looking for, it returned a data frame of survival objects.

Comment: I think I see my misunderstanding.  Does `as.data.frame(unclass(model$y))` give you what you need?  And for the full data frame, you could use `as.data.frame(cbind(unclass(model$y), model$x))`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want by using `as.matrix`:

```
pl <- as.matrix(model$y)
as.data.frame(pl)
```